# JDK8 - The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved

Tags: java, java-8

I am using `java.util.TreeSet` Class in my project. It compiles perfectly with JDK7, but when i am using JDK8 to compile the program. It is showing compile time error.

```
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Is it some encoding issue or something else?
how can i resolve this?

Comment: The only times I get errors similar to this are when I accidentally remove the JRE System Library from my build path in Eclipse. I remember someone else having a similar issue on here, but I can't remember the solution...

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I am using glassfish that might be using compiler internally. so shd i update it?

Comment: No harm in at least trying the latest GlassFish version. A question about [using lambdas in GF4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139794/glassfish-server-does-not-work-with-jdk-8) provides some answers and can be relevant to you too.

Comment: Glassfish up-gradation solve my problem.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my glassfish application server and it has been solved my problem.

Comment: Be careful of Myeclipse Tomcat server . So just download the version of `Tomcat` that support `JDK 8`, it will be fixed. **newly updated Tomcat 6/7/8** already fixed this problem~,  [tomcat.apache.org](http://tomcat.apache.org/) .  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I've met this using Tomcat 7.0. I solved it by upgrading Tomcat to 8.0 or replacing the ect.jar to the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

@Sky provided the only suggestion that worked for me - in tomcat/lib replace ecj-x.jar with the newer version.